# Can Siri shortcuts be configured to mail a link to myself?

Tags: siri

Yes, I still use my inbox as a todo list. Can I use Siri shortcuts and trigger it by saying “Mail this to me” or similar? When I try it always wants a subject line, but I want it automatically from the web page.

Comment: What do you mean by this "I want it automatically from the web page"? Can you add the link? If I understand correctly, this is a good question, just needs clarification.

Comment: That the subject of the email is just the title of the web page and Siri doesn’t ask me for a subject - it just sends the mail and disappears taking me back to Safari

Comment: Oh I see, hmm. I this should be possible. I will looking and answer soon :)

Comment: Would a share sheet icon work for you? (You press the export button [like how you would text or email it] and you select your shortcut)

Comment: "Mail this to me" the "this" is a vague definition, that is why Siri is asking you for subject.

Comment: I have a share icon already. It requires me to press Shortcuts then Mail to Self icon then wait about 5 seconds while the mail is sent in the foreground. It’s not very friendly

Comment: @NicCottrell That maybe the best you can do.

Comment: I really miss [MailToSelf](https://www.producthunt.com/posts/mail-to-self)